# Tranquility server would not send data to druid

Tags: python, server, druid

I'm using `imply-2.2.3`. Here is my tranquility server configuration:

```
{
  "dataSources" : [
    {
      "spec" : {
        "dataSchema" : {
          "dataSource" : "tutorial-tranquility-server",
          "parser" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "parseSpec" : {
              "timestampSpec" : {
                "column" : "timestamp",
                "format" : "auto"
              },
              "dimensionsSpec" : {
                "dimensions" : [],
                "dimensionExclusions" : [
                  "timestamp",
                  "value"
                ]
              },
              "format" : "json"
            }
          },
          "granularitySpec" : {
            "type" : "uniform",
            "segmentGranularity" : "hour",
            "queryGranularity" : "none"
          },
          "metricsSpec" : [
            {
              "type" : "count",
              "name" : "count"
            },
            {
              "name" : "value_sum",
              "type" : "doubleSum",
              "fieldName" : "value"
            },
            {
              "fieldName" : "value",
              "name" : "value_min",
              "type" : "doubleMin"
            },
            {
              "type" : "doubleMax",
              "name" : "value_max",
              "fieldName" : "value"
            }
          ]
        },
        "ioConfig" : {
          "type" : "realtime"
        },
        "tuningConfig" : {
          "type" : "realtime",
          "maxRowsInMemory" : "50000",
          "windowPeriod" : "PT10M"
        }
      },
      "properties" : {
        "task.partitions" : "1",
        "task.replicants" : "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "spec": {
        "dataSchema" : {
          "dataSource" : "test",
          "parser" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "parseSpec" : {
              "timestampSpec" : {
                "column" : "timestamp",
                "format" : "auto"
              },
              "dimensionsSpec" : {
                "dimensions" : [
                  "a"
                ],
              },
              "format" : "json"
            }
          },
          "granularitySpec" : {
            "type" : "uniform",
            "segmentGranularity" : "hour",
            "queryGranularity" : "none"
          },
          "metricsSpec" : [
            {
              "type" : "count",
              "name" : "count"
            },
            {
              "type": "doubleSum",
              "name": "b",
              "fieldName": "b"
            }
          ]
        },
        "ioConfig" : {
          "type" : "realtime"
        },
        "tuningConfig" : {
          "type" : "realtime",
          "maxRowsInMemory" : "50000",
          "windowPeriod" : "P1Y"
        }
      },
      "properties": {
        "task.partitions" : "1",
        "task.replicants" : "1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "properties" : {
    "zookeeper.connect" : "localhost",
    "druid.discovery.curator.path" : "/druid/discovery",
    "druid.selectors.indexing.serviceName" : "druid/overlord",
    "http.port" : "8200",
    "http.threads" : "40",
    "serialization.format" : "smile",
    "druidBeam.taskLocator": "overlord"
  }
}
```

I have trouble sending data to the second datasoruce, `test`, specifically. I tried to send the below data to druid with python requests: 

`{'b': 7, 'timestamp': '2017-01-20T03:32:54.586415', 'a': 't'}`

The response I receive:

```
b'{"result":{"received":1,"sent":0}}'
```

If you read my config file you will notice that I set `window period` to one year. I would like to send data in with a large time span to druid using tranquility server. Is there something wrong with my config or data?